# Waterfall chart issue

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I'm trying to create waterfall chart with some values and everything is working fine except the positions of bar.

As per the requirements banking solutions bar should show above the ATM services. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do this because I'm getting dynamic chart.

I'm, completely new with this and any help will be appreciated. Thanks

[image: Waterfall bar chart issue.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the column total that you need to check.
Double-click a data point to open the Format Data Point task pane, and check the Set as total box.

Please view the image -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Waterfall charts are constructed with columns for increase, decrease and total. You can select which column should be a total. Please refer to the Microsoft Support article for Waterfall charts, and format your columns accordingly.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-waterfall-chart-in-office-2016-8de1ece4-ff21-4d37-acd7-546f5527f185